# Is there a reference set of standard battery types / codes?

Tags: battery

I've seen batteries types referred to with three digit codes such 096, 047.

Are these standardised and if so is there a comprehensive that lists all of them or are they simply brand-specific model numbers?

In particular, there are batteries which seem to have different codes e.g. 048, 053, 158 that all seem to be very similar or identical specifications. If these are simply brand-specific model numbers, then I guess this is to be expected, but if these are industry-standard codes are there subtle differences between these types that I have missed? If not, the next question would be "why are there three different codes for the same thing"?

Answer (score 1):

Automotive batteries are broken down into group sizes. There is a code which specifies the physical size of the battery. The designations were set down by a group called the [Battery Council International (BCI)](https://batterycouncil.org/). Here is a blurb from [this website](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/r/advice/car-maintenance/battery-size-chart):

> The Battery Council International (BCI) has created designations known as group sizes that provide a battery's exact physical dimensions. They provide the length, width, and height in both inches and millimeters. Before you start researching other characteristics like the cold cranking amp (CCA) rating and terminal position, it's good to start by consulting a battery size chart.

I believe the numbers that you are quoting have to do with date codes. The date codes are based on the what the manufacturer wants them to be. There are several other numbers which can describe batteries, such as cold cranking amps (CCA), cranking amps (CA), reserve hours, etc. These are fairly easy to figure out and every battery, even at a given group size, can have different values in this area.

Here are the group sizes (also from the above website):

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed and informative response. A little more research suggests that surprisingly, this seems that this information differs from country to country.
Looks like what I'm interested in is the British Battery Manufacturers Society codes, although they don't seem to publish them. Instead I found this: https://www.yuasa.co.uk/info/technical/understanding-the-specifications/